# Would this work OK with a Raspberry Pi instead of a monitor?

Tags: hdmi, screen, display

Would this TV ([Furrion 19" HD Ready 720p LED TV Freeview](http://www.ebuyer.com/389617-furrion-19-furrion19-eby)) be a suitable option instead of a monitor?

I need something for my son's Raspberry Pi, and I thought this would do instead of a monitor. An added bonus is that he would have a TV too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oi Dave. Welcome to Pi Q&A. Please ask your questions with as much detail as possible. Try and write proper English as other non English users also visit this site. There is no need to 'TIA' and trust me; It is in out best interest to answer your question. Please read the [FAQ](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Any TV marked with `HD` will have at least 1 HDMI input (video/audio) and is at least 720p. `Full HD` means it supports resolutions of 1080p but still only needs at least 1 HDMI input. HDMI can also act as output for recorders if it has a built in decoder or something.

Comment: If you're using a TV attached to a computer for something other than just watching video, in addition to an HDMI port you need to make sure it has an option for a 1:1 output.  Many TVs crop a few dozen pixels off each edge of the image and scale the remainder back up.  This is a holdover from the analog CRT era when TVs were generally adjusted so that the edge of the image was on part of the glass behind the bezel to make it fully fill the screen.  It continues in the current era because "bigger is better" works on the subconscious and enlarging the image slightly makes the TV seem bigger.

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at the specifications (shown below) of this Furrion 19" HD TV, you see that it has HDMI input (actually 3), for the Raspberry Pi this is all that is needed to successfully use this combination.

```
SPECIFICATIONS

Max. resolution:                1366 x 768@60Hz HD
Power supply:                   100V-240VAC 60/50Hz
Power consumption (standby):    < 1.0W
Speaker:                        3W x 2
Pixel pitch:                    0.30 x 0.30
Viewing angle:                  170º/160º
Luminance white:                250cd/m
Contrast ratio:                 1000:1
Wall mounting (mm):             75 x 75

CONNECTIONS

VGA:              1
HDMI:             3   <--------
USB:              1
AV in:            1
YPbPr:            1
Headphones:       1
Scart:            1
RF:               1
S-video:          1
Digital out:      
Digital noise reduction:     YES
10 Bit colour dispose function:  YES
```

Comment: Please provide some more references. And also quote them here with the relevance model number etc for SEO.

Answer (score 2):

It will work. It has two HDMI ports that Raspberry Pi can use. You can see them on your picture, two horizontal sockets to the left from the blue one. These are HDMI ports.

You will need to connect Raspberry Pi to one of these sockets and select that socket as a source using the remote for that TV.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. I assume that each TV will be OK to support your RaspberryPi. It has both HDMI and RCA video outputs which should be suitable for both new (each has some HDMI inputs) and older TVs.

What is more you can buy also ordinary monitor (it could be just waste of money to buy TV just to plug it to Raspberry). If you will find one that has DVI input it could be fine. Since both HDMI and DVI standards are quite similar you will need just DVI to HDMI converter.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely go for the TV, and use HDMI. You may find (depending on the TV firmware) that the remote can be used to control the Raspberry Pi for media centre-like use, and this is an added bonus.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works with noobs as well